# Return Type incompatible with Object.getClass()

Tags: java, eclipse, auto-generate

the code is generated upon importing a webservice file on eclipse. However, I saw this error upon compiling (return type incompatible with `Object.getClass()`).

Any ideas to fix this?

```
public java.lang.String getClass(){
    return localClass;
}
```

Add On:

```
   if (localClass != null){
                                            elementList.add(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(localClass));
                                        } else {
                                           throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("Class cannot be null!!");
                                        }
```

Comment: Please give more information. What is `localClass`?

Comment: Hi All, I tried to add a final keyword public final.. and it worked. Any ideas why I didn't have an error now?

Comment: I am facing the same error, i added final it did not work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I take it your web service is given as WSDL file. From this WSDL file some Java files are automatically generated. Apparently, your WSDL file contains a property named "class" and thus the corresponding generated Java class has a getter for this property called `getClass()`.

However, `getClass()` is a method which is defined in the `Object` class and all Java classes inherit from `Object`. Java thinks you are trying to override this method., which is not allowed, because 1) the method is final, and 2) the return type doesn't match.

You might want to look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342360/jaxb-classes-from-schema-generates-getter-setter-method-in-uppercase), which mention how you can rename the property so that its getter doesn't conflict with standard Java methods.

Comment: This is my very exact problem. I'll look onto this one.

Comment: nice one there.

Answer (score 1):

[`getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) is a final method of `Object` which returns a `Class`. You are getting that error because the compiler thinks you are trying to override `getClass` while changing the return type to something that is not a `Class`. If you want to return a `String` you will need to change the method name to something else or add parameters to the method so its signature does not match `Object#getClass`. Note that you can't override it even if you want to return a `Class` because it is final.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  java.lang.String getClass(){
              return localClass;
   }
```

can be changed with

```
 public  Class<?> getClass(){
              return localClass;
 }
```

But as getClass is final method this cannot be overidden. If you want your own method then consider changing name.

Comment: I tried it but the error is that it cannot convert string to class.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually prefer:

```
public final Class<? extends Object> getMyClass(){
    return localClass;
}
```

Which is generic. Since everything in Java inherits from Object, this matches everything loaded on the classpath. And you probably have issues because you are trying to override the `final` method `.getClass()` (so the name here is `getMyClass()` instead.

From the javadoc of [`.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) you can see that:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the `static` type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

Comment: I tried it but the error is that it cannot convert string to class.

Comment: Please post more code so we can see how you **use** this method exactly. Edit your question with it